# Dos and DDos attacks in UAV

Tags: denial-of-service

Are modern-day UAVs secured from Dos or DDos attacks? Most of the drones available in the markets are easily hackable with the help of Dos attacks be how secure the UAV-GS authentication is. Moreover, drones available in the market are vulnerable to jamming signals, thus stopping the entire communication. One interesting thing is that how secure we make the UAV-Ground Station communication, a simple attack like Dos on a drone can disrupt the entire communication with the GS, and the same goes with the jamming signal as well.

So anyone working in this field, how are you guys dealing with Dos attacks and jamming signals, given that the computational strength is limited and we have memory constraint as well in UAVs, given that UAVs must be lightweight and also cost-cutting is a factor.